# How to remove or disable add -row and delete-row action button from yupgrid?

Tags: javascript

I am using yup grid for client side data entry. It is has actions column (containing add-row and delete-row buttons) by default. My requirement is to show add-row and delete-row action buttons to specific users only. For unauthorized users I do not even want actions column. I searched a lot in documentation [here](https://yupgrid.com/Documentation/index?topic=defining%20action%20buttons%20in%20YupGrid%20(member%20of%20options%20object)), but can not find any solution. Please help me on this.

```
var data = [];
var ddlData = [{    "ratingID": "1","rating": "1"}, {"ratingID": "2","rating": "2"}, {"ratingID": "3","rating": "3"}];
var gridObject = [];
var options = {
    tableID: "appList",
    debugLog: false,
    singleClickEdit: true,
    allowEmptyRows: false,
    autoStyle: true,
    onRowChange: function (e) {
        //save data
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url",
            data: {
                data: JSON.stringify(e.yupObj.data[e.dataRowIndex]),
                isNew: e.yupObj.data[e.dataRowIndex].isNew()
            },
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    },
    columns: [{
            headerText: 'App',
            columnName: "appName",
            dataType: "any",
            dataValueMember: 'appName',
            dataTextMember: 'appName',
            hidden: false
        },
        {
            headerText: 'Type',
            columnName: "rating",
            dataType: "any",
            dataValueMember: 'ratingID',
            dataTextMember: 'rating',
            hidden: false,
            inputControl: {
                controlType: 'select',
                dataTextMember: 'rating',
                dataValueMember: 'ratingID'
            }
        },
        {
            headerText: 'App ID',
            columnName: "appID",
            dataType: "any",
            dataValueMember: 'appID',
            dataTextMember: 'appID',
            hidden: true
        },
        {
            headerText: 'Category',
            columnName: "categoryID",
            dataType: "any",
            dataValueMember: 'categoryID',
            dataTextMember: 'categoryID',
            hidden: true
        }
    ]
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    gridObject = yupGrid(options);
    options.columns[1].dataSource = ddlData;
    options.columns[1].bindData();;
    gridObject.bindData(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code in onBindDataComplete event. This event is triggered when bindData finishes loading data.

```
yupObj.onBindDataComplete = function(){
   $('#appList tr td .grid-row-icon-a[id*="addRow_"]').remove();
};
```

Similarly you can remove delete button also.

Alternately you can use [onBeforeRowDelete](https://yupgrid.com/Documentation/index?topic=onBeforeRowDelete%20Event%20(events%20in%20options%20object)%20%20(member%20of%20options%20object)) and [onRowInsert](https://yupgrid.com/Documentation/index?topic=onRowInsert%20event%20of%20grid%20(events%20in%20options%20object)%20%20(member%20of%20options%20object)) events to restrict addition or deletion of rows.